# Python 3 Mechanical Soup - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nonetype, mechanicalsoup

I'm a newbie trying to set up a webscraper using Python 3 and Mechanical Soup. The website I'm trying to scrape requires a login and I can't seem to submit my login details.

```
browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()

# Request page
login_page = browser.get("https://www.website.com/login")

login_form = login_page.soup.find("form", {"id":"login"})

# specify username and password
login_form.find("input", {"id": "username"})["value"] = 'myUsername'
login_form.find("input", {"id": "password"})["value"] = 'myPassword'

# submit form
response = browser.submit(login_form, login_page.url)
```

The error I'm getting is from the last line (response = browser.submit...).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\blahblahblah\webscraper.py", line 144, in <module>
        main()
    File "C:\blahblahblah\webscraper.py", line 69, in main
        response = browser.submit(login_form, login_page.url)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\browser.py", line 117, in submit
        request = self._prepare_request(form, url, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\browser.py", line 111, in _prepare_request
        request = self._build_request(form, url, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\mechanicalsoup\browser.py", line 54, in _build_request
        for input in form.select("input"):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Printing out login_form provides

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.website.com/login" class="content-container blockform" id="login" method="POST"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="h8Sg8QdB08xyLQ4pUPcdnOHb90h0mHJownN7E7V0" />
<h1>Login</h1>
<fieldset>
<legend>Login Information</legend>
<dl>
<dt><label for="username">Username</label></dt>
<dd>
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" />
</dd>
<dt><label for="password">Password</label></dt>
<dd>
<input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" value="" />
</dd>
</dl>
</fieldset>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> You will remain logged in until you press the logout button.</p>
<a class="button" href="https://www.website.com/recovery"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Forgot password?</a>
<button class="button green" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</button>
</form>
```

and printing login_page.url provides

```
https://www.website.com/login
```

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://piratefache.ch/python-3-mechanize-and-beautifulsoup/

Anyone know what's going on and can help?

Comment: always put FULL error message in QUESTION - there are other usefull information, ie. which line makes error.

Comment: error means that you have `None` in variable and now you try to do `variable()` which means `None()`

Comment: Just added the rest of the error message. Which variable would be None? I've already shown what 'login_form' and 'login_page.url' are

Comment: problem is when you execute `submit()` - without real url I can't test it and check problem.